# which is the best design pattern in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

which is the best design pattern in objective c?

please specify useful links to see before we go to dive to code!!!!!

because everytime while i go to dive straight to code i confused at middle of some point.To clear this we have to make first design then we can implement them.

please specify any useful links.

Comment: A design *pattern* is not in and of itself a design.

Comment: Best for what? There's no objectively correct answer to this so-called question. -1.

Comment: u can refer the "raywenderlich" blog for tutorial
[http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns)

Answer (score 4):

Design patterns are many and no one is the best. They typically solve different problems in different domains. You can check out the book [Cocoa Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321535022), it should provide enough text and code to help you choose which pattern you need to use for your problems. :-)

Answer (score 2):

the 'best' for what? they do different things.

anyway, here's an intro:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about UI (your question is not clear), I'd start [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG).